# How to iterate an array of objects and only get specific values

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have an array of below format

```
[{
    "_id" : "500",
    "loanRef" : "500",
    "createdTime" : "2018-02-15T17:20:47.156Z",
    "bdetails" : {
        "config" : {
            "chase" : [
                6,
                12
            ],
            "expiry" : 35
        }
    },
},
{
    "_id" : "500",
    "loanRef" : "500",
    "createdTime" : "2018-02-15T18:11:45.377Z",
    "bdetails" : {
        "config" : {
            "chase" : [
                6,
                12
            ],
            "expiry" : 35
        }
    },
}
}]
```

The above array size is around 200..

But I want this in this format

```
[{
    "_id" : "500",
    "loanRef" : "500",
    "createdTime" : "2018-02-15T17:20:47.156Z",
    "chase" : "[6,12]",
    "expiry" : 35           
},
{
    "_id" : "500",
    "loanRef" : "500",
    "createdTime" : "2018-02-15T18:11:45.377Z",
    "chase" : "[6,12]",
    "expiry" : 35
}]
```

Can someone help how we can form this with some js logic..Any help would save me with this.Thanks

Comment: [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: you need to take a look at the map() function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use functions `forEach` and `JSON.stringify` along with `Spread operator (...)`.

```js
var array = [{     "_id" : "500",     "loanRef" : "500",     "createdTime" : "2018-02-15T17:20:47.156Z",     "bdetails" : {         "config" : {             "chase" : [                 6,                 12             ],             "expiry" : 35         }     }, }, {     "_id" : "500",     "loanRef" : "500",     "createdTime" : "2018-02-15T18:11:45.377Z",     "bdetails" : {         "config" : {             "chase" : [                 6,                 12             ],             "expiry" : 35         }     }, } ];

array.forEach((o) => {
  Object.assign(o, o.bdetails.config );
  o.chase = JSON.stringify(o.chase);
  delete o.bdetails;
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Well, they OP did ask that the `"chase"` will be convert to a sting, but that is definitely  a great answer with or without that part

Comment: Almost worked but I need chase value to be saved a string
i.e.,"chase":"[6,12]"

Comment: @hammy I'm going to fix it

Comment: That @Ele .It worked.Small doubt what does 3 dots (...) represent here?

Comment: @hammy Spread Operator/Syntax.  Actually, you don't need to execute that Spread operator.   [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array.map` to transform each item into some other object;

```js
const data = [{
    "_id": "500",
    "loanRef": "500",
    "createdTime": "2018-02-15T17:20:47.156Z",
    "bdetails": {
      "config": {
        "chase": [
          6,
          12
        ],
        "expiry": 35
      }
    },
  },
  {
    "_id": "500",
    "loanRef": "500",
    "createdTime": "2018-02-15T18:11:45.377Z",
    "bdetails": {
      "config": {
        "chase": [
          6,
          12
        ],
        "expiry": 35
      }
    },
  }
];

const result = data.map(item => ({
  "_id": item.id,
  "loanRef": item.loadRef,
  "createdTime": item.createdTime,
  "chase": JSON.stringify(item.bdetails.config.chase),
  "expiry": item.bdetails.config.expiry
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a detruction for the wanted properties and return a new object with it.

```js
var array = [{ _id: "500", loanRef: "500", createdTime: "2018-02-15T17:20:47.156Z", bdetails: { config: { chase: [6, 12], expiry: 35 } } }, { _id: "500", loanRef: "500", createdTime: "2018-02-15T18:11:45.377Z", bdetails: { config: { chase: [6, 12], expiry: 35 } } }],
    result = array.map(
        ({ _id, loanRef, createdTime, bdetails: { config: { chase, expiry } } }) =>
            ({ _id, loanRef, createdTime, chase: JSON.stringify(chase), expiry })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: But how can we get chasevalue as string

i.e., "chase": "[6,12]"

Comment: you could use `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
objects.map(o => ({
    _id: o._id,
    loanRef: o.loanRef,
    createdTime: o.createdTime,
    chase : o.bdetails.config.chase,
    expiry : o.bdetails.config.expiry
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without prototype functions:

```
 function map(arr) {
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var item = arr[i];
            item['chase'] = item.bdetails.config.chase;
            item['expiry'] = item.bdetails.config.expiry;
            delete item.bdetails;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the use of `delete`, you can iterate the old array and add only the data you want to the new one.

Also, I've write it in a way I think it's more easy to adapt to different situations.

```
let newArray = [];

oldArray.forEach( e => {
  let obj = {};
  Object.keys(e).forEach( k => {
    if (k != "bdetails"){
     obj[k] = e[k];
    }else{
     obj.merge(e[k]);
    }
  });
  newArray.push(obj);
)
```

Comment: This answer requires more details. See «[explaining entirely]» thread (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Comment: @Stphane you're right. I've just edited it and added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
var a = [{...},{...}]     
for (var i = 0;i < a.length; i++) {
      var temp = {}
      temp['_id'] = a[i]['_id']
      ...
      a[i] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another take on ES6 destructuring with `map`:

```
const out = data.map(({ bdetails: {config: { chase, expiry } }, ...rest }) => {
  return { ...rest, expiry, chase: JSON.stringify(chase) };
});
```